# bleachbit wiped my free space and now showing 0 byte available

Tags: 16.04, crouton, bleachbit

i am using Ubuntu using crouton in Chromebook, i installed bleach bit to delete cache and temp files and it accidentally wiped all my free space which was 7 GB before wiped after running bleach bit Ubuntu automatically logged out and now showing 0 byte and i cannot login to Ubuntu through chrome OS because its showing no space left in the device.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the giant file in  ~/.cache using `rm -rf ~/.cache` or use BleachBit to delete system temporary files. This assumes you have a relatively newer version of BleachBit, or the large file may be in another location.

Ubuntu repositories often have old versions, so try to update from www.bleachbit.org

Answer (score 1):

Tools which wipe your free space often work by simply writing a file that fills up the rest of the partition, until all clusters are occupied.  This file is supposed to be deleted afterwards.  It seems this didn't happen, which could indicate that the wiping didn't complete either.

There are some problems with this approach:

- Completely filling up the hard drive, even for a short time, can make other programs or services crash or malfunction.
- Linux file systems often reserve a certain amount of space, eg 5%, for use by the superuser only, so that system services have access to some disk space if users fill up the drive.  So if you run these tools as a regular user it will leave 5% of the drive un-wiped anyway.
- Modern SSDs reserve some additional free space outside of its stated capacity in order to dramatically speed up writing, but this happens at a level the operating system cannot see or control and therefore it's not possible to wipe all space on an SSD.

The first two issues can be avoided if you do it on a non-live system (eg from a Live CD or USB rather than from the drive you're actually operating on) as superuser.  As for the third issue, sometimes the SSD manufacturer provides a tool specifically for wiping the SSD.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by:

1. Press hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd> to switch to TTY session on a different virtual console.
2. Then run the following command:

   ```
   rm -rf /home/username/.cache
   ```

   Remember to replace `username` with your actual username.